# Azure function accessing connection string from configuration

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I have hosted Azure Function V3 on Azure Linux environment. I am trying to read the connection string from the configuration section. But I am not getting it. I tried to put the connection string on both, `Application Settings` as well as `Connection Strings` sections as shown below.

[image]

I am using dependency injection and my `Startup` class looks like below.

```
using BHD.Data.Data;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(BHD.AzureFunctions.Startup))]
namespace BHD.AzureFunctions
{
    class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var sqlConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(sqlConnection));
        }
    }
}
```

I get `NullPointerException` on `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString` even though the connection string exists in `local.settings.json` file as shown below.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "<My connection string>"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried reading an environment variable instead?

Comment: @CarlosGarcia, yes I had tried environment variable which worked, but I wanted it to work with `Connection Strings` settings. Sellotape's answer below helps. Thank you!

Comment: For anyone still interested I described possible approaches here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74312224/8833279

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way to get configuration in Azure  Functions 2+ is `IConfiguration`, not `ConfigurationManager`.

You can inject `IConfiguration` into most places where you might inject anything else, but in `Startup()` you need to use something like [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60791103/azure-function-v2-and-connection-strings/60792224#60792224) instead.

`IConfiguration` will automatically read from your function app settings when hosting in Azure, and your `local.settings.json` when run locally.

---

**Edit** (references):

The documentation for this is IMHO neither clear nor easy to find.  There is also a lot of related discussion and confusion on GitHub.

The main source is [DI in Azure Functions 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection).  Within it, [most of what you need to know](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#function-app-provided-services) is almost easily missed:

> The function host registers many services. The following services are safe to take as a dependency in your application:
>
> [...] `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration` [...]

It also, in [Working with options and settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#working-with-options-and-settings) says:

> Values defined in app settings are available in an IConfiguration instance

The host does this for you; you do not need to do anything, and as above, it automatically gets settings from the correct source depending on your hosting context.

Comment: Thank you, Sellotape, may I know where did you find to use `IConfiguration`? It would be great if you can link to the page.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal - I've updated the answer with some refererences.